# save-some-buffers diff prevents scrolling

Tags: diff, save

After invoking `save-some-buffers`, I almost always want to check the diffs with `d`. But when I do so, I'm not able to do any scrolling in the diff window, nor to change its size, or indeed any window's size, until I have decided whether to save the buffer or not. This makes it impossible to read all but a portion, defeating the purpose for me.

Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: No, that is definitely not the intended behavior. The `diff` window is in `view-mode` where scrolling forward/backward is done with `SPC`/'DEL' and I can change its size (e.g. by click-dragging the mode line of the window above). I can also change the size of other windows. What happens if you do `C-h` in the `diff` window? Do you get the help prompt?

Comment: @NickD If I try to activate the diff window, it rings the bell and the minibuffer remains active. (Weird)

Comment: This looks like an emacs bug, it should be possible to scroll the diff with `C-M-v`. If you set `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t` you'll end up with a `diff` window in `view-mode`.

Comment: Ah, right - `enable-recursive-minibuffers` is set to `t` in my case.

Comment: So my testing was off, and there's no emacs bug: `C-M-v` scrolls the `*Diff*` buffer for me, but `ESC C-v` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*Diff*` buffer can be scrolled up and down respectively with <kbd>C-M-v</kbd> and <kbd>C-S-M-v</kbd>.  If you scroll it past its end, it will be removed from view.

Alternatively, set `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t`, then <kbd>d</kbd> will place you in the `diff` buffer, with `view-mode` enabled, which allows you to scroll with <kbd>DEL</kbd> and <kbd>SPC</kbd>.